# Laravel Carbon, InvalidFormatException, unexpected data found. Does anyone understand what this error message is saying?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I was attempting to run my website with 'php artisan serve' and got the following error message. Does anyone know what it's trying to tell me or how to fix the issue? For context I'm new to programming with laravel and python, also not all the code wrote is my own I'm working with other people.

```
Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException 

Unexpected data found.

at vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php:687
683▕             return $instance;
684▕         }
685▕
686▕         if (static::isStrictModeEnabled()) {
➜ 687▕             throw new InvalidFormatException(implode(PHP_EOL, $lastErrors['errors']));
688▕         }
689▕
690▕         return false;
691▕     }

1   vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php:710
Carbon\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat()

2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:303
Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat()
```

I have googled the issue and found similar error messages but not the same, attempts to work this out with other team members has not helped. I have reinstalled npm, reset my system clock, deleted the database and re-migrated, and finally looked at all code using the createFromFormat function the result being code that was already part of laravel and there were no errors; none of this has helped. Ideally the website would be running after entering 'php artisan serve'. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Post your entire stacktrace from the error log. The data that is passed to Carbon is invalid. Find out that data that is passed, dd that data and then try to debug your poblem

Comment: The error is pretty clear - Carbon received some data in a format it does not understand.  So the 2 bits of info you need to look at (and supply here) are 1) the data you supplied (probably some form of date string), and 2) the code where Carbon is trying to use that data.  You should find the latter by looking through the full stack trace, the former you'll need to work out based on what that code is doing.